# How to recover Windows 8 authenticated users access if denied for a particular folder

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, file-permissions, administrator

I've got Windows 8 and trying to restrict access to a particular folder on my D: drive for other user accounts, and set permissions for the authenticated user group in security tab as denied. Now I can't open it through my standard account and the administrator account as well.

Comment: @wonea Please don't forget looking at the titles as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To recover security settings, you have to become *owner* of the folder:

1. Open folder properties.
2. Click **Security** tab.
3. Click **Advanced** button.
4. Click **Owner** tab.
5. Click **Edit**.
   Confirm elevation if UAC prompt is shown.
6. Select your user account in the **Change owner to** list.
7. Optionally select **Replace owner on subcontainers and objects** check box.
8. Click **OK**.
9. Click **OK** to close *Advanced Security Settings* and *Properties* dialogs.

When you reopen the folder properties dialog, you'll be able to edit security settings and grant access to yourself.